# Add prefix to each array object with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I prefix to each 'name' in my array with js when it looks like this :

```
models:[,…]
[0 … 99]
0:{name: "something", value: "something",…}
[100 … 199]
[200 … 241]
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: This should work for you: `models = models.map(function(x) {
    x.name = 'PREFIX' + x.name;
    return x;
});` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
arr.map(r => {
    r["name"] = "prefix_" + r["name"]
    return r
})
```

Comment: Correct, but just be careful recommending ES6 syntax without a warning about compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Answer (score 0):

you should have researched more before asking.
anyways this will do:

```
models = models.map(function(item){
            item.name = "prefix" + item.name;
            return item;
        })
```

Comment: Researched more like in the comments sections..?

Answer (score 0):

Transforming an array with objects can be done using `.map`. Map takes the function that should be applied to each element in the original array.

```
const PREFIX = 'TEST';
const prefixedModels = 
  models.map(model => ({...model, name: PREFIX + model.name}));
```

I use the spread operator to first "copy" every exiting property, to make sure that other properties don't get lost.